# inject cookie into Chrome using Windows Form App in VB

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, firefox, cookies

I need to inject a cookie into FireFox and Chrome via a Windows Form App written in VB.  I have not been able to find any code or documentation online for this.  The sample below is how I did it for IE, but I do not know where to begin with FireFox or Chrome.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Option Explicit On
Module createCookie
Private Declare Function InternetSetCookie Lib "wininet.dll" _
    Alias "InternetSetCookieA" _
    (ByVal lpszUrlName As String, _
    ByVal lpszCookieName As String, _
    ByVal lpszCookieData As String) As Boolean

Private Declare Function InternetGetCookie Lib "wininet.dll" _
    Alias "InternetGetCookieA" _
    (ByVal lpszUrlName As String, _
    ByVal lpszCookieName As String, _
    ByVal lpszCookieData As String, _
    lpdwSize As Long) As Boolean

Public Function setCookie(cookieExpTimeGMT As String)
    Dim bRet As Boolean

    bRet = InternetSetCookie("http://testsite.com", "CookieName", "Cookie Value" & "; expires = " & cookieExpTimeGMT)

        Return bRet
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Evidentially you haven't tried anything beside's telling us `you have been able to do this for IE`... Please tell us what you have tried and ***what doesn't work***.

Comment: Sorry... I have been searching online for a couple of days now and I don't even know where to begin. The sample I gave was to give an example of what I want to do but in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my question.  Firefox and Chrome both use SQLite DB files to store the cookies.  One can use System.Data.SQLite (google search for download) to write a cookie into the DB file.  Expiration date is different from Firefox and Chrome.  Chrome is number of Micro Seconds from 1/1/1601 and Firefox is number of seconds from 1/1/1970.

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite
Imports System.Environment

Module createCookieChrome
Public Function setChromeCookie(newValue As String, orgValue As String, cookieExpTimeGMT As String, hostName As String, cookieName As String, currentTime As String)
    Dim fRtn As Boolean = False
    Dim chromeCookiePath As String, strDb As String


    chromeCookiePath = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies"
    If chromeCookiePath = Nothing Then
        fRtn = False
    Else
        Try
            strDb = "Data Source=" + chromeCookiePath + ";pooling=false"
            Dim SQLConn As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection(strDb)
            Dim SQLcmd As SQLiteCommand = SQLConn.CreateCommand()

            SQLcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `cookies`(`creation_utc`,`host_key`,`name`,`value`,`path`,`expires_utc`,`secure`,`httponly`,`last_access_utc`,`has_expires`,`persistent`,`priority`,`encrypted_value`) " & "VALUES (" & currentTime & ",'." & hostName + "','" & cookieName & "','" & newValue & orgValue & "','/'," & cookieExpTimeGMT & ",1,1," & currentTime & ",1,1,1,'')"
            SQLConn.Open()
            Dim rtV As Int64 = SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            SQLConn.Close()
            fRtn = True
        Catch e As Exception
            fRtn = False
        End Try
    End If

    Return fRtn

End Function
End Module
```

Comment: how can you ExecuteNonQuery() when chrome is running?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't work around that. Chrome will have to be closed so the app will need to run before chrome is launched.  FireFox does not have this limitation.